# how to automatically increment count and display it in layout page when a new record added in database using mvc without refresh using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, jtable

I have one table named announcement when a new data added on this announcement table the count which dispalyed in the _layout.cshtml from a partial view of the same table.. this partial view dispalys the announcements description with count as on the top of the div,. if we add a new announcemetnt on announcement table the count should be automatically incremented without whole page refresh what can i do for this? 
the code inside the main controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Create(Announcet announcement)
        {

            try
            {
                ValidatePageControls(announcement);
                //populate error message if model state is not valid
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    string errorMsg = GetErrorMessage();
                    return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = errorMsg });
                }
                else
                {
                    string entityName = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Announcement>().EntitySet.Name;
                    //used to add sequence.
                    Int32 nextVal = new PanERP.Common.Common().getNextSequence(entityName);
                    announcement.AnnouncementId = nextVal;

                    // Set CREATED_BY & CREATED_DATE ...

                    db.Announcement.Add(announcement);
                    //save the entity in DB
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return Json(new { Result = "OK", Record = announcement });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message });
            }
        }
```

the code inside the partiall view controller

in layout pagere one option is present to increment the count of announcemetn when a new record added in it.. but the count should come after page refresh .. how can i change that

Comment: please help me for this..

Comment: I am not sure that this will be possible without using AJAX or jQuery. You can easily grab the number with jQuery and increment it, but you would really need to know that it had updated correctly before you incremented it.

Comment: by using jquery and ajax how can we do it? plz give me a solution for this i'm new in mvc

Comment: actually i have 2 view and 2 controllers.. one controller is to add the datas in announcemnt table in database .. another one is to display the partial view ie display all the announcements as in a partial view with count i want to increment this count without page refresh

Answer (score 1):

Like Gaz said in the comments, you can't really make a number of records increase without checking your database and counting. You could increment it client side if the user themselves added a record, but if someone else at the same(ish) time has added a record as well then you're count will go out of sync.

From your comment if looks like you are very new to MVC and using AJAX, I would heartily recommend taking a look at the tutorials available on [asp.net/mvc](http://www.asp.net/mvc), particularly the Pluralsight training videos. For this particular problem there is a [whole chapter dedicated to using AJAX with MVC4](http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=mvc4-building-m6-ajax&mode=live&clip=0&course=mvc4-building).

I'm aware this doesn't answer your question but you are unlikely to get an answer as you're question is very vague and doesn't really fit with the questions that are meant to be asked on here. Check out the tutorials, see what you can do and then come back if you hit a more specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: ya, i'm taking the count from database by writing linq query in controller.. its not the matter of sync i have one back end table to prevent this sync .. its actually a jtable. if u don't understand my question i'll explain u once more time.

Comment: Okay, I see. You may want to edit your question and expand it, judging by the comments and the downvote people don't fully understand your question. Identify a single problem and explain it thoroughly. The more thoroughtly you explain it the more likely people won't get the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: i have edited the question this question now also u won't able to understand? if u understand the question give me a solution for this.. please......

Comment: can anyone able to answer this questn?